# rails 5 update attribute only if it's currently nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

What is the preferred way in Rails 5 with activerecord to update the attribute only if it is currently nil.

```
car = Car.first
car.connected_at = Time.zone.now
car.save

OR

car = Car.first
car.update!(connected_at: Time.zone.now)


it should update only if car.connected_at is nil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply check for [#nil?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F)

```
car = Car.first
car.update_attribute(:connected_at, Time.zone.now) if car.connected_at.nil?
```

> That's not generic enough. I want something like before_validation etc. I am just not sure which way is the preferred one.

Well if you want to go for validation, it would look something like this..

```
before_save :validate_connected_at

private

def validate_connected_at
  connected_at = connected_at_was if connected_at_changed? && connected_at_was.present?
end
```

OR

```
before_save :set_connected_at

private

def set_connected_at
  connected_at = Time.zone.now if connected_at.nil?
end
```

As you can see, more checks, more methods. I would definitely go for the first one.

However, if you want to add error message, then this is the way

```
errors.add(:connected_at, 'Already present!')
```

> So "#{attr}_was" is always available on all the defined attrs in before_save method?

They are available in general and not only in `before_save`, e.g. in the console..

```
car = Car.first
car.connected_at
=> 'some value'
car.connected_at = 'some other value'
car.connected_at
=> 'some other value'
car.connected_at_was
=> 'some value'
```

Comment: That's not generic enough. I want something like before_validation etc. I am just not sure which way is the preferred one.

Comment: I am not sure if it's right. I wanna do sth like here is the param. Check in the db it's currently present. If it is, do nothing otherwise use the param. What you recommended is: if the param is nil use Time.zone.now

Comment: Just to be clear, You are in your controller, receiving value in param? If the param is nil, you want a default value of `Time.zone.now`?

Comment: The point is it shouldn't matter. If I am anywhere in the app or rails console and wanna update the `connected_at` value either with `update` or  'save' etc. then it should check if `connected_at` is nil for that particular instance in the db. If it is nil then use the `connected_at` value that I pass in either from controller/ console/ model/ etc.. If the `connected_at` is present in the DB then disregard the value that was passed in to the save/update/etc.

Comment: In that case, `before_save :validate_connected_at` this is the solution as it will always check for the value before updating it.

Comment: Ahh ok. So `"#{attr}_was"` is always available on all the defined attrs in `before_save` method?

Comment: Updated the answer for better understanding

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: glad to help.. :)

Comment: You forgot to use `self` for the setter. Can you update your answer for others?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying you want to modify the behaviour of how a particular attribute works so it quietly ignores you. I think the instinct behind why you want to seal this off is reasonable one but if you think about it a bit more you might consider that if you do this kind of thing in a lot of places then using your objects will start to become confusing particularly for someone else who doesn't know the code well.

Perhaps you want to do this because there's other code using the Car model that wants to make connections but doesn't really have the full picture so it tries stuff which you only want to succeed the first time. It's much better to handle such operations solely inside a class which does have the full picture such as the Car model or a service object.

If you still really want to control this "connecting" behaviour outside the Car then you can override the attr_writer completely in the Car class. I'd definitely recommend doing this on before_save callback instead though.

```
def connected_at=(new_value)
  if @connected_at
    raise StandardError, 'connected_at has already been set'
  end
  @connected_at = new_value
end
```

That will work whichever way you try to assign the value. If you're wondering about what's going on above have a read about attr_accessor in ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's not the case. I just made up the `Car` model here. I have rabbitmq sending an event if sth is connected as a boolean. The event can be sent severeal times though with other data (I have no control over the events). I wanna save the boolan as datetime to see when the first connected: true was sent and disregard the new ones if they are the same

Comment: That's a fair reason. You can still use the above suggestion but without the error throwing bits and @connected_at ||= new_value . Better would be an explicit method named notify_connection

Answer (score 0):

this is my understanding of your question.

- Car can update only if `connected_at` is `nil`

  ```
  class Car < ApplicationRecord
      before_save :updatable?

      def updatable?
          connected_at.blank?
      end
  end
  ```

The point is return `false` when before_save.

Comment: It's not that. The accepted response is correct. The details are in that comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
car = Car.first
car.connected_at ||= Time.zone.now
car.save
```

That will only assign if `connected_at` is `nil` of `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to use the `before_update` callback and rephrase the intention of the OP as "discard updates if my attribute already has a value".

I came up with this solution (which works well with mass assignments such as `Car.update(car_params)`):

```ruby
before_update :ignore_updates_to_connected_at

def ignore_updates_to_connected_at
  return unless connected_at.present? && connected_at_changed?

  clear_attribute_change(:connected_at)
end
```

The `<attribute_name>_changed?` and `clear_attribute_change` methods come from [ActiveModel::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).